# jquery AOP:Define many targets for the same method name with the same advise

Tags: javascript, aop

i use AOP Jquery which is licensed as following :

```
/**
* jQuery AOP - jQuery plugin to add features of aspect-oriented programming (AOP) to jQuery.
* http://jquery-aop.googlecode.com/
*
* Licensed under the MIT license:
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*
* Version: 1.3
*
* Cross-frame type detection based on Daniel Steigerwald's code (http://daniel.steigerwald.cz)
* http://gist.github.com/204554
*
*/
```

could i define many targets  when i have the same method name in these targets :

Example:

```
  var Person={
       doctor:{

          setResume:function(){
           }  

        },
        engineer:{

          setResume:function(){
           }  

        }
}
```

Instead of  :

```
$.aop.before({
    target:Person.doctor,
    method:'setResume'},function(args) {
        console.log('setResume will be called '):

    }
});

$.aop.before({
    target:Person.engineer,
    method:'setResume'},function(args) {
        console.log('setResume will be called '):

    }
});
```

i want for example:

```
$.aop.before({
    target:[Person.doctor,Person.engineer],
// or target :'Person.*' ...
    method:'setResume'},function(args) {
        console.log('setResume will be called '):

    }
});
```

Comment: Curious why you posted the license? Is that related to the question in some way?

Comment: Regarding the `AOP` tag, wrapping and reassigning already declared functionality (be it functions or methods) misses any aspect of _AOP_. Any language which wants to qualify for the latter has to provide abstraction levels for at least `Joinpoint`, `Advice` and `Aspect`. The use case described by the OP should be referred to as method modification, and JavaScript of cause is well suited for this scenario and could easily provide a complete `target`/`context` aware toolset of method modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally` via `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if,it looks like, no, as @mgroves said , the safety method is :

```
$.aop.beforeMultiple = function() {
    var targets=arguments[0].target;
    for(var i =0;i<targets.length;i++)
     {
        arguments[0].target=targets[i];    
        $.aop.before.call(this, arguments);
     }
}
```

because arguments of `$.aop.before` are :

= Arg1: an Object: `{target:Aaaa,method:'yyy'}`

=Arg2 : a function : `function(args){}`

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick review of the [jQuery AOP source code](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/source/browse/src/aop.js), it looks like, no, that won't work. However, I don't see why you couldn't create a patch to allow for that behavior, or suggest that feature to the owner, or maybe just create your own helper function.  Something like this (untested, consider it pseudo-code):

```
$.aop.beforeMultiple = function(targets, method) {
    for(var i =0;i<targets.length;i++)
        $.aop.before(targets[i], method);
}
```